# Integration of tinyMce with LWC is not working

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service, lwc-dom, third-party

I am trying to use `tinyMce Rich text editor` in an application based on LWC instead of lightning-input-rich-text.

> I uploaded tinymce.min.js file in static resources and is using that
> in my component

Please see my component code below:

**applicationPortalContainer.js**

```
import tinymceJS from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/tinymce';
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class ApplicationPortalContainer extends LightningElement {
  renderedCallback() {

    Promise.resolve(loadScript(this, tinymceJS)).then(() => {
      const textArea = this.template.querySelector('.editor');
      try {
        tinymce.init({
          target: textArea
        });
        console.log('success');
      } catch(e) {
        console.log('exception', e);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

**applicationPortalContainer.html**

```
<template>
   <textarea class="editor" lwc:dom="manual">
   </textarea>
</template>
```

Here the tinymce js file is getting loaded and I am getting success in console but the **textarea is not getting initialized as tinymce editor**, its still showing as textarea element with a `visibility: hidden` inline style added to it.

What is rendered in DOM looks like:
[image]

Any help to render the tinymce editor within LWC will be highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: hey Aditya, did you get it working with TinyMce now ? I dont see any errors too and locker service seem to work ok as well

Answer (score 1):

This might have to do with `locker-service` in which it prevents any dom modification, and seeing the library, it will definitely modify the dom. Check this : https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console.

Copy your js and paste it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console) and check if the library is able to access all the required APIs.

As a workaround if this `tinyMce` library is required at any cost, use it in a `VisualForce` page and then host that VF page as an `iframe` in LWC. For communication between your VFPage and LWC component you can use `postMessage`, if required.