# Send color changed text to rich text editor in salesforce .This is to implement custom mention in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I was able to send the text with changed color to the rich text editor, but when ever I click the editor, this is replaced with `<p>` tag. Is there any way to avoid this?

**HTML**

```html
<lightning-input-rich-text
    value={myVal}
    class="input"
    onchange={handleInputChangex}
>
</lightning-input-rich-text>
<lightning-formatted-rich-text value={myVal}></lightning-formatted-rich-text>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement} from 'lwc';
myVal1 = 'Introductory mail on <span style="color: blue;">cars and bikes </span>';
export default class Custom_mention_sample extends LightningElement {
}
```

Comment: So what you want it should be span tag or without any tag?

Comment: i want with span tag and it should not change while editing it in rich text editor.

Comment: Are you saying in the text editor you are seeing 
<p> Introductory mail on <span style="color: blue;">cars and bikes </span> </p>
?

Comment: I purposed one solution please check and let me know if it works.

Comment: yes. i am able to do it. but if i click on the editor it goes back to <p> Introductory mail on cars and bikes </p>

Comment: @Gopal This will replace the whole text. Is there a any way i can retain the tags in rich text editor after edit?

Comment: May I ask you, if you can add a photo which can provide more information on what you mean? Because, I deployed the code with some minimal changes, when I change the value, I do not see the <p> tag in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to allow users to input and edit rich text content with HTML tags, you may need to consider using a third-party rich text editor component that supports HTML rendering and editing within LWC. Some popular options include Quill, TinyMCE which offer more customization and control over the HTML content. You can integrate these editors into your LWC component and handle the HTML content as per your requirements.

References to look : [Has anyone implemented custom mentions in LWC?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/339605/has-anyone-implemented-custom-mentions-in-lwc)

[Integration of tinyMce with LWC is not working](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/327158/integration-of-tinymce-with-lwc-is-not-working)

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 0):

Changing is default behaviour of that but what we can do to achieve is you can replace the p tags will span tags from HTML when onchange event occur.

```
// Sample HTML content
const htmlContent = '<p>This is a paragraph.</p> <p>Another paragraph.</p>';

// Replace all <p></p> tags with <span></span> tags
const replacedHTML = htmlContent.replace(/<p>(.*?)<\/p>/g, '<span>$1</span>');

console.log(replacedHTML);
```

Comment: This will replace the whole text. Is there a any way i can retain the tags in rich text editor after edit?